# show a div with every socket connection

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

I'm trying to show a div every time a client connect. For exemple whene the first client connect div1 shows, the whene the seconde client connect the div2 shows ...etc . I managed to do the first connection, but i couldn't do the rest. 
here is the code for the client side :

```
socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
    // Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

    if(data.isConnected == true) {
        // Now hide the div.
        getElementById("div1").style.display:"block";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("#parent-div")
socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
    // Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

    if(data.isConnected == true) {
       parent.innerHTML += "<div class='new-div'></div>"
    }
});
```

Is this what you mean? This would set a DOM object as the div you want to add to, then on each isConnected socket event, it would add a new div under the parent div

EDIT: vanilla JS instead of jQuery

Comment: first of all : i have 8 divs and for every socket connection i want to show a div.

Comment: secondlly : i liked your idea, you mean with every socket connection i create a new div ? that is what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, since it sounds like the divs you are showing are just hidden to begin with, and are incrementally shown, you might as well just create new ones and add them to the DOM instead of having a set amount you want to show that are hidden. Now you can add as many as you want

Comment: and for the server side ? i don't add any thing ? just socket.on(''connection", function () { socket.emit("isConnected" , {isConnected: true}) }

Comment: Isn't the client side event called `connect` ? So `socket.on('connect')` on client side and `on('connection')` on the server side?

Comment: yes is it , i mean there is no special thing to add on the server side !?

Comment: Not for the addition of divs unless you want to supply data that is going to go into those divs

Comment: and all the divs will have the same classe ? because i want them to be placed in the right , left , top, and down the screen. how i can manage that ?

Comment: That should be under a different question as you are now talking HTML and CSS layouts. I think your initial question has been answered